# Regarding aligning two spans side by side with only one text overflow

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to align text as in screenshot. The first span is overflowing and it should display ellipses but, second clear all should always be displayed at right hand of last span element.

[image]

```html
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 filter-display-bar"
     title="{{vm.filterSelectionsTitle}}"
    >
     <span>
      {{vm.filterSelections}}
                    </span>

     <span class="clear-all" title="Clear All"
                            ng-show="vm.listOptionResorts.length !== 0 || vm.listOptionStatus.length !== 0 || vm.listOptionArrivalDate.length !== 0 || (vm.startTime !== undefined && vm.startTime !== '') || (vm.endTime !== undefined && vm.endTime !== '')"
                            ng-click="vm.clearEverything()">
                         Clear All 
     </span>
                    
    </div>
```

```css
div.filter-display-bar{
    width: 90%;
    .heightFifty;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
    font-family: Avenir-Book,Helvetica,Arial;
    font-style: Book;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #000;
    line-height: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    span.clear-all{
        color: #40A8E2;
        cursor: pointer;
        width: 84px;
        background-color: #F2F2F2;
        position: fixed;
        right: 104px;
    }

}
```

Something like this actually, -

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this which I think provides the elements you asked for:

```css
.filter-display-bar {
  overflow: hidden;
  line-height: 1.1;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
.long-text {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: calc(100% - 60px);

  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;  
  overflow: hidden;
}

.clear-all {
  display: inline-block;
  color: steelblue;
  cursor: pointer

  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<br>
<br>
<div class="filter-display-bar">
    <span class="long-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod.</span>
    <span class="clear-all">
        Clear all
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: I do not want it to be always in right 0 but always on the next side of first span.

Comment: @Smitha Updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

Look at my solution. I used position absolute for `span.clear-all`. Also I set `padding-right` to `div.filter-display-bar` which equals to `span.clear-all` `width`. Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Stafox/qpu6xb3x/